# Search using keyword to the article subject and article content

Tags: api, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Is it possible to search salesforce knowledge articles using keywords to their title and content? I've known that rest api have this

> https://***yourInstance***.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/search/?q=FIND

but I have problem on what to put for the query. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FIND` is part of SOSL. It's a "full text search" engine which has different syntax than the "normal" SQL / SOQL. SOSL is what powers the global search (top of the page in both classic and lightning UI)

The full syntax looks bit scary: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm (this link leads to SOQL and SOSL reference guide, there's a comparison chapter too)

Some example searches (on normal objects, nothing really Knowledge-specific) can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm

Something Knowledge-specific... start with these two and experiment:

```
FIND {Keyword}
RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion (Title WHERE PublishStatus='Online' and language='en_US')

FIND {some search words} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Faq__kav(KnowledgeArticleId, Title, Summary, UrlName WHERE PublishStatus ='Online' AND Language = 'en_US' LIMIT 5) WITH SNIPPET(target_length=300)
```

queries on Knowledge require specifying article status (published/drafts/archived ones) and language code so that's why even in basic form you need a WHERE clause. 1st sample will scan all articles in your org but if you have mutliple article types you might want to explicitly specify the type.

So yeah, now at least you have some reading material. Try going through the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_sosl) too and post another question if you're stuck with something specific?

Comment: thank you for the reply. It gives me some idea now. But I have problem in putting it to my url, can you atleast give me example on how to do it? I am using ajax get for my calls

Comment: I like using https://workbench.developerforce.com for experiments, once you're in go to Utilities -> Rest Explorer. Try this url: `/services/data/v41.0/search?q=FIND+{Uni}+IN+ALL+FIELDS+RETURNING+Account(Id,+Name,+Description),+Contact(Id,+LastName,+Email),+User`. In a typical Developer Edition with same preloaded data it should return (among others) University of Arizona, United Oil&Gas + their contacts...

Comment: `FIND+{"\(415\)+901\-7000"}+IN+PHONE+FIELDS+RETURNING+Account(Id)` for exact match (double quotes) and escaping special characters like parentheses and dashes.